# Is it allowed to ask questions about errors launching a game on arqade?

Tags: support

Well I am having a Microsoft .NET Framework error when launching Batman Arkham Asylum GOTY edition and I was wondering if Arqade is the right website to ask it on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to answer without seeing the actual question, but in general these kinds of technical-support questions are on-topic on this site - since you are asking as a user of the game, not as a programmer.

Comment: I'll just try it on arqade. Thanks anyway man.

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to ask - your question shouldn't be closed - but to be perfectly honest troubleshooting issues is not (yet?) one of our strengths.

Comment: Yeah that's why I was thinking if a different stack exchange website would be a better idea, but ok i'll ask on arqade